# Is SQL Injection possible in this case (REGEXP)?

Tags: web-application, appsec, sql-injection, databases, mysql

I'm on a website which have a program, there is a search input for keywords.

When I input `&` or `<` or `>` and search, it returns `Got error 'empty (sub)expression' from regexp` error and when I input `$` or `^` or `.*` I get all keywords at once, which seem like its relying on `REGEXP` function from MySQL to match.

Ok, so I have tried `aaaaaaa' OR SLEEP(999) -- -` but output was:

> Unfortunately! aaaaaaa\' OR SLEEP(9999) -- - is out of stock

Ok,so `'` is getting escaped and becomes `\'`, then I tried with `\'` to see if only `'` is getting escaped, but it seems that both of them gets escaped:

> Unfortunately! aaaaaaa\\' OR SLEEP(9999) -- - is out of stock

`3 \` not 2 like in blockquote

I've also tried url encoding and I got same output.

By the way the app is using PHP and MySQL

Answer (score 1):

You can't invoke a command from a regex, so you can't do an SQL injection in this case.

However, you could enter a very long processing regex that would certainly cause issues with the web site. For example forward lookahead with multiple wildcards (see [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)).

Here is an example (in Java regex):

```
\(([$_a-zA-Z][$_a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:\.[$_a-zA-Z][$_a-zA-Z0-9]*)*(?:,[$_a-zA-Z][$_a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:\.[$_a-zA-Z][$_a-zA-Z0-9]*)*)*)*\)
```

The syntax that your regex uses may be slightly different, but this is the general idea.